# UITextView scrollEnabled = YES not working after set scrollEnabled = NO in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I create a demo for checking `UITextView scrollEnabled`. 
It only contains 1 `UITextView` and 2 button enable and disable scroll

- I test on simulator and device iOS 8, if I click the disable scroll button, the `UITextView` will disable scroll correctly, but after that I 
  click on enable scroll, the `UITextView`  **won't** enable scroll
- However, I test on device iOS9, the enable and disable scroll work well.

  ```
  #import "ViewController.h"

  @interface ViewController ()

      @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
  }

  - (IBAction)enableScrollButtonPressed:(id)sender{
      self.myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
  }

  - (IBAction)disableScrollButtonPressed:(id)sender{
      self.myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
  }

  @end
  ```

Any idea to fix this problem? If someone don't understand my explain please check 
[my demo project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_poNaia6t8kV3MtODM5TjdhUTQ)
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated

Comment: in simulator or device

Comment: @PKT in both simulator and device

Comment: i tried you code text view not scrolling until  you change orientation

Comment: issue is with the auto layout i fixed height of textview  and now able to scroll

Comment: @PKT I try fixed the height of the textview using autolayout. but my textview still not able to scroll after I click disable then enable scroll :(

Comment: you are right in that was not working if you find solution then please share thnx

Comment: am glad to know how you do with the autolayout. i dont know how to do autolayout. if you have any type of helping materials please share to me

Comment: @PhanVănLinh please see my answer

Comment: This is bug in Xcode.. Try Setting it by using code after ViewDidAppear  get called. Then and then it iwll work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that in iOS 8, contentSize is not adjusted correctly when scrollEnabled is changed. A small adjustment to your enableScrollButtonPressed method will successfully work around the problem.

```
-(IBAction)enableScrollButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    self.myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.myTextView.contentSize = [self.myTextView sizeThatFits:self.myTextView.frame.size];
}
```

Comment: Looks like this may be back in iOS 12...at least, this fixed a very similar issue for me

Answer (score 6):

Yeah you are right disabling and enabling scroll of textview is not working in iOS8 it may be a bug or anything else, let it be.
We can disable or enable scroll of text view by just **changing the ContentSize of textview** .

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

@end

 @implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)enableScrollButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.bounds.size.width+20, self.myTextView.bounds.size.height+20);
    [self.myTextView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
}

-(IBAction)disableScrollButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    [self.myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [self performSelector:@selector(StopScroll) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

-(void)StopScroll{
    CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.bounds.size.width, self.myTextView.bounds.size.height/2);
    [self.myTextView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
}

@end
```

I had tested the above code it is working fine for me i'am using **xcode 7.2.1** and **iOS 8.3**. Give it a try and let me know the result

Comment: thank you for your effort. this solution work well. However, can you check the @Brett Donald answer, does it better?

Comment: Welcome Phan,I tried brett donald's code in your demo project something works strange.Try the below scenario 1.Once your app runs, scroll text view to top then disable scroll and enable it again is it working for you ?. 2. Sometimes tapping enable button twice changes the textview frame.

Answer (score 5):

[image]After searching hours i am found one way

```
-(IBAction)enableScrollButtonPressed:(id)sender{
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self.myTextView setText:self.myTextView.text];

    self.myTextView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false;

});

}

-(IBAction)disableScrollButtonPressed:(id)sender{

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
});

}
```

condition for that is you need to scroll first then you it will work perfectly

Means when disable scroll button is tapped textview should be scrolled at some position  ***must not to at default position***

Comment: thank you so much for your effort. This solution work but it will change the text size of TextView after disable then enable scroll. I think the solution given by @Brett Donald is better. Do you think so?

Answer (score 4):

```
Please follow below steps simply
self.myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to layout your views after enabling or disabling scroll view in your view.

use viewWillLayoutSubviews/layoutIfNeeded methods.

Comment: I have used layoutIfNeeded and viewWillLayoutSubviews but it still not work. maybe the way i'm using is wrong. Can you help me in code or please check my demo project

Answer (score 3):

change your property as follows.

in your code..

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;
```

change property attribute as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;
```

then it'll work fine. i checked it.

Comment: ohh.. let me check again.

Comment: it is bad to set IBOUTlet to strong

Comment: yeah. i was looking for an alternative extraction

Answer (score 2):

I tried my code and it worked properly

```
IBOutlet UITextView *tv;

//---------Enable button action.

-(IBAction)enable:(id)sender
{
    tv.scrollEnabled=YES;
}

//---------Disable button action.

-(IBAction)disable:(id)sender
{
    tv.scrollEnabled=NO;
}
```

try your code once more in device.

Comment: did you check it in simulator/device iOS8?

Comment: i checked it in both simulator and device

Comment: yeah sure. let me check

Comment: change your property attribute to strong from weak. then it will work fine. i got it working fine. can i show the solution as another answer? i didn't changed anything in your project except this property attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```